# Need some basic documentation for publishing page editors

Tags: list, document-library, publishing-site, training

Can you point me to some documentation for SharePoint 2010 beginners who need to edit publishing pages? They need to perform basic tasks, such as applying markup styles, pasting text, inserting and editing tables, inserting pictures and links, etc. In addition, they will be editing items in lists and libraries.

The editors are not familiar with HTML and are comfortable only with the GUI editor in the browser. We need to provide them with documentation but didn't want to re-invent the wheel.

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start exploring with following link:

[SharePoint 2010 Resources for End Users](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/Pages/End-User-Training-Guide.aspx)

The one that you are particularly interested in is:

[SharePoint pages II: Work with wiki pages](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/sharepoint-pages-ii-work-with-wiki-pages-RZ101837218.aspx)

[SharePoint pages I: An introduction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/sharepoint-pages-i-an-introduction-RZ101837217.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. Any tutorials on publishing pages/sites?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-web-content-management-RZ101857171.aspx

Comment: Editing Publishing pages should not be much different from editing wiki pages, so look for 2nd link in my answer.